# Cannot deploy app on SharePoint

Tags: visual-studio, ms-office, office-addins, office-js

So I have a PowerPoint Web Content Add-In app (same as the default app that comes preloaded), that I want to test by running on Office 365 Developer account. I have Visual Studio 2015 Community.

Here is XML file (with ID stuff removed)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<OfficeApp

 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1"

 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

 xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0"

 xsi:type="ContentApp">

<!-- Begin Basic Settings: Add-in metadata, used for all versions of Office unless override provided. -->

<!-- IMPORTANT! Id must be unique for your add-in, if you reuse this manifest ensure that you change this id to a new GUID. -->

<!--Version. Updates from the store only get triggered if there is a version change. -->

<Version>1.0.0.0</Version>

<ProviderName>[Provider name]</ProviderName>

<DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>

<!-- The display name of your add-in. Used on the store and various places of the Office UI such as the add-ins dialog. -->

<DisplayName DefaultValue="PowerPointWebAddIn12" />

<Description DefaultValue="PowerPointWebAddIn12"/>

　

<!-- Domains that will be allowed when navigating. For example, if you use ShowTaskpane and then have an href link, navigation will only be allowed if the domain is on this list. -->

<AppDomains>

<AppDomain>AppDomain1</AppDomain>

<AppDomain>AppDomain2</AppDomain>

<AppDomain>AppDomain3</AppDomain>

</AppDomains>

<!--End Basic Settings. -->

<Hosts>

<Host Name="Presentation" />

</Hosts>

<DefaultSettings>

<SourceLocation DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/Home/Home.html" />

<RequestedWidth>400</RequestedWidth>

<RequestedHeight>400</RequestedHeight>

</DefaultSettings>

<Permissions>ReadWriteDocument</Permissions>

</OfficeApp>
```

[image]

I go to my Office 365 developer site:

[image]

Press the "new app to deploy button" and successfully upload my app to developer site:

[image]

But get this error when I deploy:

[image]

Could you please help?

Comment: There seems to be a step missing from your description:  What is this package you generated, and how did you generate it?  If it was done through Visual Studio (which presumably it was), what are the project properties for the top (manifest) project?

Comment: Package generated through visual studio. Project properies for the manifest are in the updated question.

Comment: When you say "package generated through visual studio", what do you mean by package?  Is a manifest XML file a package?  And does generated mean through some sort of "publish"-like action, or just the file as you have above?

Comment: By "package", it is literally the files generated by VS when you select and create a new project, unchanged. I'm not sure what you mean by your second question, its just the XML file inside the manifest package. There was a "publish" action that I try to do, and it fails. Please help me @MichaelZlatkovsky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your XML file, you still have tokenized values like "~remoteAppUrl".  You need to get your XML file to a clean/publishable state.

Publishing it is the simplest way, you can follow the steps on https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/officeapps/2014/01/15/publishing-apps-for-office-and-sharepoint-to-windows-azure-websites/.

Since you'll need to host the web page somewhere, the same blog post will also help you get the application to an Azure Website (though you can also use localhost if it's just for testing -- if so, choose "Create new profile" instead of choosing an existing one.